# R markdown html document not properly show in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, r, internet-explorer, activex, r-markdown

I create a `rmarkdown html document` and following is my code:

````
---
title: "PA" 
output: 
  html_document:
    css: custom.css
    theme: journal
    toc: true
    toc_float: 
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
    toc_depth: 4
---
<style>
.list-group-item.active, .list-group-item.active:focus, .list-group-item.active:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
#TOC {
  color: purple; 
}
.toc-content {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
h1 { /* Header 1 */
 color: DarkBlue;
}
</style>

<div class="datatables html-widget html-widget-static-bound"
     id="htmlwidget-3efe8ca4aa087193f03e"
     style="width:960px;height:500px;">

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(knitr)
library(htmltools)
library(scales)
PA <- read.csv("PA.csv" , header = T , colClasses = c("Year"="factor", "Month"="factor"))
PA$Month <- as.numeric(as.character(PA$Month))
PA$Year <- as.numeric(as.character(PA$Year))
PA$date_label <- ymd( paste( PA$Year, month.abb[ PA$Month ], 01, sep = "-"))
```

```{r include = FALSE}
# If I want to use for-loop to print htmltools::tagList, this chunk is very important.
# However, I don't know why must need it.
DT::datatable(PA, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = list(c(I('colvis'), 'copy', 'print'), list(extend = 'collection',
        buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
        text = 'Download'
)), searchHighlight = TRUE
))
ggplotly(ggplot(PA))
plot_ly(PA)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results = 'asis'}
red.bold.italic.text <- element_text(face = "bold.italic", color = "red")
colors <- c('rgb(211,94,96)', 'rgb(128,133,133)', 'rgb(144,103,167)', 'rgb(171,104,87)', 'rgb(114,147,203)')

for(i in unique(PA$Products)) {

  cat("  \n#",  i, "{.tabset .tabset-pills}  \n")

  cat(paste("## Summary"), sep = "\n")

  print(knitr::kable(mutate(summarise(group_by(PA[PA$Products == i,], Year, Company),sum(EPSUM), sum(Incurred)), LR.percent = `sum(Incurred)`/`sum(EPSUM)`/0.01), format = 'html'))

  cat(paste("## Line Graph {.tabset .tabset-pills}"), sep = "\n")

   cat(paste("### Line1"), sep = "\n")

   print(htmltools::tagList(
           ggplotly(ggplot(PA[PA$Products == i,], aes(x=date_label , y=EPSUM, col=Company , group=Company))
                  + geom_line(size = 1)
                  + scale_x_date(name = "Month", date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "2 month" )
                  + labs(title = "EPSUM", x = "Time", y = "") 
                  + theme(title = red.bold.italic.text, axis.title = red.bold.italic.text) 
                  + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
)))

   cat(paste("### Line2"), sep = "\n")

   print(htmltools::tagList(
           ggplotly(ggplot(PA[PA$Products == i,], aes(x=date_label , y=EPSUM, col=Company , group=Company))
                  + geom_line(size = 1)
                  + scale_x_date(name = "Month", date_labels = "%b %Y", date_breaks = "5 month" )
                  + labs(title = "EPSUM", x = "Time", y = "") 
                  + theme(title = red.bold.italic.text, axis.title = red.bold.italic.text) 
                  + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
                  + facet_wrap(~Company)
)))

  cat(paste("## Bar Chart {.tabset .tabset-pills}"), sep = "\n")

   cat(paste("### BAR1"), sep = "\n")

   print(htmltools::tagList(
          ggplotly(ggplot(summarise(group_by(PA[PA$Products == i,], Year, Company), sum(EPSUM)), aes(x=Year, y=`sum(EPSUM)`, fill=Company))
                  + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
                  + labs(title = "EPSUM", x = "Time", y = "")
                  + theme(title = red.bold.italic.text, axis.title = red.bold.italic.text) 
                  + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
)))

   cat(paste("### BAR2"), sep = "\n")

   print(htmltools::tagList(
           ggplotly(ggplot(summarise(group_by(PA[PA$Products == i,], Year, Company), sum(EPSUM)), aes(x=as.factor(Year), y=`sum(EPSUM)`, fill=Year))
                  + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
                  + labs(title = "EPSUM", x = "Time", y = "")
                  + theme(title = red.bold.italic.text, axis.title = red.bold.italic.text) 
                  + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
                  + facet_wrap(~Company)
)))

  cat(paste("## Pie Chart"), sep = "\n")

  print(htmltools::tagList(
          plot_ly(summarise(group_by(PA[PA$Products == i,], Company, Year), sum(EPSUM)), labels = ~Company, values = ~`sum(EPSUM)`, type = 'pie',
                  textposition = 'inside',
                  textinfo = 'label+percent',
                  insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
                  hoverinfo = 'text',
                  text = ~paste(Company, 'EPSUM', `sum(EPSUM)`),
                  marker = list(colors = colors,
                                line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),
                                showlegend = T) %>%
        layout(title = '',
               xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
               yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)) 
  ))

  cat(paste("## Table"), sep = "\n")

  print(htmltools::tagList(
          DT::datatable(PA[PA$Products == i,][,c(-1,-12)], extensions = c('Buttons','Scroller'),
                        rownames = F, selection = list(target = 'row+column'),
                        options = list(pageLength = 400, dom = 'Bfrtip', scrollY = 200, scroller = TRUE,
                           buttons = list(c(I('colvis'), 'copy', 'print'), 
                                     list(extend = 'collection', buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                                          text = 'Download')), 
                           searchHighlight = TRUE)) %>% 
          formatCurrency(4:10, '', interval = 3, mark = ",")
))

  cat("  \n")
}
```
````

data introduction:
5191 obs. of 11 variables (variables are not important, just know that there are 6 variables should remember: `Products`, `Year`, `Month`, `Company`, `EPSUM`, `Incurred`)

My question is: when I knit the `html document`, it takes too much time, is there any way to decrease the time?
After I knit, *Internet Explorer* cannot properly show, but *Google Chrome* can. I think it is because **ActiveX**. However, after I open it, it still cannot properly show. Any suggestion?

Not properly show.
[image: not propeely show]

It should show like this.
[image: properly show]

I think this post also figures out many other users' questions about how to use for-loop in R markdowm. And there are few reference on StackOverFlow.

Very appreciate.

Comment: Decrease time: take advantage of [`knitr` cache](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/). IE-vs-Chrome: you say "*Chrome can*" then say "*it still cannot properly show*", which is it? Have you tried reducing the problem to see what exactly causes it to not display correctly in IE? Reduction helps you narrow down the suspects, and will increase the likelihood of getting help here.

Comment: I edit my question, thank you